# What causes Error 1463999005 during deployments

Tags: deployment, error-messages

We are attempting to deploy a large batch of metadata and are receiving this error:

> objects/MyObject__c.object (MyObject__c.MyField__c) -- Error: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: [##########] (1463999005)

What causes this unexpected error?

Answer (score 2):

This error arises if the field already exists in the target org but has a different field type. Usually in this case, you will receive a more helpful error message like "Error: Cannot update a field to a Formula from something else". But in some cases it just fails with this error message.

The resolution is to delete that field in the target org before deploying the field with the updated field type.